# Stack vs heap -- speed of access, creation and deletion

Tags: c++, memory

Q1. I need to call a subroutine 1000s of times. This subroutine does work based on different input values. This subroutine *needs* to allocate and deallocate space for objects of classes that do the work. The question is whether to have this subroutine allocate and deallocate space on the stack or the heap.

```
int main(){
    for(int param = 1; param <= 10000; param++)
        int retval = subroutinecall(param);

}

int subroutinecall(int param){
    Classname* objptr = new Classname;//Heap allocation
    int retval = objptr->dowork(param);
    delete objptr;
    return retval;
}
```

versus

```
int subroutinecall(int param){
    Classname obj;//Stack allocation
    int retval = obj.dowork(param);
    return retval;
}
```

Is there any reason for speed and efficiency reasons to use the heap allocation instead of stack allocation here? From what I gather, the stack allocation might fail if `Classname` is a big object requiring more space than available on the stack. Is this the only case (where the object is big) where heap allocation should be preferred?

Q2. In terms of passing around objects' (big or small) pointers around different functions, is there any performance penalty to using stack as opposed to heap?

```
int main(){
    Classname* objptr = new Classname;//Heap allocation.
    subroutine(objptr);
    delete objptr;
}
```

with corresponding

```
void subroutine(Classname* objptr){
    objptr->dowork();
}
```

versus

```
int main(){
    Classname obj;//Stack allocation
    subroutine(obj);
}
```

with corresponding

```
void subroutine(Classname& obj){
    obj.dowork();
}
```

Is there any reason to prefer one version over the other in this case?

Comment: In general, prefer stack allocation for a known number of objects whose lifetime ends after this function. Use heap allocation for a dynamic number of objects or for objects whose lifetime must extend beyond the function all. In terms of speed, profile your program. There's no substitute for measurement. Heap allocation speeds will vary across platforms.

Comment: `passing around objects` Neither of the examples passes an object. Both the pointer and the reference refer back to the same existing object.

Comment: The question is extremely generalized. If you want the best results, you cannot ask for a specific solution to a generalized problem. Show the real use-case.

Comment: @dxiv neither of the examples copies the object, but "passing" is an abstract term isn't it? This looks like passing to me.

Comment: @JohnFilleau If there is no copy involved then Q2 reduces to Q1.

Comment: @dxiv You are right. I have edited the OP. In both cases the reference/pointer are passed. From what I gather, the reference in many cases is implemented as a pointer. So, I have indicated only pointer in the OP.

Comment: @dxiv that may be the case, but my argument wasn't whether two questions were warranted. My argument was that calling this "not passing" is wrong. Passing variables by reference, pointer, or copy are all valid ways to pass a parameter.

Comment: @Tryer Then Q2 is redundant. At that point memory is memory, and you don't expect the speed of `subroutine` to depend on the particular value of the pointer passed to it.

Comment: @dxiv the location of the object in memory could matter if cache is limited and one option (probably stack) preserved spatial locality. But at this point the answer is "profile your particular application and find out"

Comment: @JohnFilleau A function call usually breaks locality, anyway. But, yes, profiling is the ultimate decider.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any reason for speed and efficiency reasons to use the heap allocation instead of stack allocation here?

I see no reason to expect that, especially given the lack of details. Dynamic allocation (with the global allocator) is typically significantly slower than automatic. But you can verify whether this is the case in your program by measuring, as well as whether the difference is significant in relation to the entire program.

> Is this the only case (where the object is big) where heap allocation should be preferred?

Not necessarily. In some cases lifetime of the objects can be unpredictable in which case automatic allocation is not an option.

But when it is an option, automatic allocation is usually preferable as a rule of thumb.

> In terms of passing around objects' (big or small) pointers around different functions, is there any performance penalty to using stack as opposed to heap?

There may be some minor differences in some cases. Whether those differences result in a penalty or benefit depend on the rest of the program. Typically the overhead of passing an object (regardless of where it was allocated) is insignificant in relation to the cost of dynamic allocation (with the global allocator).

---

P.S. Avoid using bare owning pointers. Your dynamically allocating version of the program will leak memory if `dowork` throws.

Comment: As pointed out by @JohnFilleau in the comment, wouldn't heap allocation within a subroutine break cache locality if I am also using other variables and data structures that are scoped within the subroutine stack?

Comment: @Tryer Potentially, yes.

Comment: @Tryer keyword from eerokia there: potentially. I want to make sure you get this, but while the academic thought exercises are FINE, if you're in a production environment where you actually care about your program's performance, then these rules of thumb are a good place to start but you need to profile to be sure.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yes, I understand that. Yet, unless one runs out of space on the stack, it is not clear to me why one would prefer a heap allocation within a subroutine at all.

Comment: @tryer You'd use heap allocation in a function when the number of objects is unknown (so you make a container) or when the lifetime of the object(s) extend beyond the end of the function.